# merge two binary images using Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I need to create two different black binary rectangles using Matlab, to overlay a part of both and to extract the insertion.

How can I overlay two binary images?

```
-------|----------|
|      |     2    |
|    1 |----|-----|
|           |
|-----------|
```

I created my two binary images using the `false(X, Y)` Matlab function.

I dont find how to produce the merge the two images and to extract the insertion.

Comment: What do you mean by insertion? Do you mean intersection? Also that function doesn't produce "images", it just produces matrices.

Comment: The insertion.. The place where the two matrix are surimpose.. you cahn do an imshow and it will output an image (false(x,y)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a background matrix that can contain both rectangles before you translate them, and assign values of the background matrix to the areas where your rectangles will be. This way you have two matrices of the same size, on which you can do logical or arithmetic operations. If you use different values for each rectangle and the background, things like sums will show up in different colors. Here's a text version that demonstrates:

```
octave:11> bga = bgb = ones(10,10)
bga =

   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1

octave:12> bgb
bgb =

   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1

octave:13> a=false(3,4)
a =

   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0

octave:14> b=false(5,5)
b =

   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0

octave:15> bga(3:5,4:7) = a
bga =

   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1

octave:16> bgb(1:5,1:5) = b
bgb =

   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1

octave:17> bga | bgb
ans =

   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: "Make a background matrix that can contain both rectangles before you translate them". The output is actually the matrix which contain the two rectangles!

Comment: I don't understand, was your question answered or not?

Comment: It was the AND operator at the end, but your answer was good. Thank you!